# Can I reference the batch file directory in a WinSCP batch script?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I am trying to upload a file to an FTP server using a batch command file. My code uses WinSCP and looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open ftp://user:pass@ftp.website.org/" ^
    "lcd %cd%" ^
    "cd /incoming/data" ^
    "put %~dp0file.txt" ^
    "exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)

exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

The log shows this:

```
> 2020-10-14 15:16:39.044 Script: put C:\Users\me\sharepoint - library folder\FTP\file.txt
. 2020-10-14 15:16:39.047 Copying 4 files/directories to remote directory "/incoming/data" - total size: 0
. 2020-10-14 15:16:39.047   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: folder\FTP\file.txt
. 2020-10-14 15:16:39.047   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2020-10-14 15:16:39.047   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
* 2020-10-14 15:16:39.048 (EOSError) System Error.  Code: 2.

* 2020-10-14 15:16:39.048 The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'm expecting `put %~dp0file.txt` to give the full path to the file I want to upload and it looks like it gets it right from the log, but I don't know why it's trying to send 4 files or why it fails to find the specified file. I should note the path (folder/ftp) is actually much longer, the full path is 102 characters. The path contains spaces and one dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path contains spaces, so it has to be [wrapped to double quotes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#quotes):

```
    "put ""%~dp0file.txt""" ^
```

---

The same goes for `lcd`. But as it makes no sense to use `lcd`, if you use an absolute path in the `put` command anyway, you can just remove the `lcd` altogether.